# Scala - Playframework - JsResultException

Tags: scala, play-json

I am trying to pass json values to my method with a POST but i'm getting the error below:

```
Handler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [scala-library-2.11.11.jar:na]
Caused by: play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))
        at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
        at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
        at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:77) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
        at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:13) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
        at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.as(JsValue.scala:65) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
```

and this happens on this variable declaration

```
  val friends = (json \ "friends ").as[JsArray].value
```

I'm able to successfully create a post using Postman without any issue when I format my json as follow

```
{"success":true,"friends":[ 
    { 
       "id":1,
       "name":"john",
       "age":"19",
    }
]
}
```

but when i reformat my json to

```
[ 
    { 
       "id":1,
       "name":"johny",
    }

]
```

I get

```
[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `.as` is unsafe.
2. There is no `friends` field in `[ { "id":1, "name":"johny", }]` (being a `JsArray` or whatever `JsValue`).